# How to inject arguments when using lazy types?

Tags: c#, unity-container, lazy-evaluation

I have a Translation class that takes in `ITranslationService` as its argument. How do I inject translation service when registering the `Lazy<Translation>` type? This is what I've done so far, but no luck.

```
public class Translation
{
    public Translation(ITranslationService translationService)
    {
        // code here
    }
}

container.RegisterType<ITranslationService, TranslationService>();
container.RegisterType<Lazy<Translation>>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ITranslationService)));
```

Error message when trying to resolve `Lazy<Translation>` type:

> The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless
>   constructor

Comment: "no luck" meaning what, exactly? (such as exact error message if you get that)

Comment: Also you seem to have mismatched angle brackets...

Comment: Could it be that you need to add `ImportingConstructor` as an attribute?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, [Unity 3 now supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170416.aspx) resolving `Lazy<T>`(See *What's New* section), so you don't need to do anything special, just register `ITranslationService` and you will be able to resolve `Lazy<Translation>`.

So the following only applies to Unity 2.

- You can install [this nuget extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Extensions.Lazy/1.1.1) from Piotr Wlodek. You will then need to enable it using:

  ```
  container.AddNewExtension<LazySupportExtension>();
  ```

  You will then be able to resolve `Lazy<T>` objects:

  ```
  var lazy = container.Resolve<Lazy<Translation>>();
  ```

  And the actual `Translation` object will not be constructed until you call `lazy.Value`.
- If neither getting Unity3 nor that extension is an option, you could still try to manually configure Unity2 and resolve those objects.

  In your case, you need to use one of the [constructors in `Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) that receives a `Func<T>` as parameter. (That is a function with no parameters that returns an instance of T, or `Translation` in your case).

  You can use  an `InjectionFactory` when registering `Lazy<Translation>` in Unity, which is a factory method that constructs a `Lazy<Translation>` object. The lazy object will receive in its constructor an initialization function that uses Unity to resolve the `Translation`:

  ```
  container.RegisterType<Lazy<Translation>>(
   new InjectionFactory(c => new Lazy<Translation>(() => c.Resolve<Translation>()) ));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Unity supports `Lazy<T>`, but you have to configure it:

```
unityContainer.AddNewExtension<LazySupportExtension>();
```

then **don't** do

```
container.RegisterType<Lazy<Translation>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ITranslationService)));
```

but instead do:

```
container.RegisterType<Translation>();
```

And use it as follows:

```
unityContainer.Resolve<Lazy<Translation>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

For any one using MVC or Web API projects, just install the relevant Unity Bootstrapper Nuget package i.e Unity.AspNet.WebApi for Web API, and Unity.Mvc for MVC.

And then register your types as you normally would, either in code or through a config file. The Lazy instances will be injected automatically

```
private Lazy<IMapService> _mapService;

public HomeController(Lazy<IMapService> mapService)
{
    //Lazy instance is injected automatically.
    _mapService = mapService

}
```